# How can I play the full animation of a class that was toggled in Javascript using .toggleClass?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am making a navbar hamburger menu animation (where when you click it turns into an x then back to a hamburger menu once u click again) and I can't get the animation to play properly. It snaps between the hamburger and x and does not play for the proper duration. I am not sure why it does that. I have in css that the animation should play for 0.5s.

```
<a onClick = {onClick}>
  <span className = 'navTrigger inactive'>
    <i></i>
    <i ></i>
  </span>
</a>
```

---

```
.navTrigger {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 44px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .navTrigger i {
      background: white;
      content: '';
      display: block;
      width:100%;
      height: 1px;
  }
  
  .navTrigger.inactive i:nth-child(1){
    transform: translateY(7px);
    animation: x_1 0.5s backwards ease-in-out;
    
  }
  .navTrigger.inactive i:nth-child(2){
    transform: translateY(-7px);
    animation: x_2 0.5s backwards ease-in-out;
  }

  .navTrigger.active i:nth-child(1) {
    animation: x_1 0.5s forwards ease-in-out;
    
  }

  .navTrigger.active i:nth-child(2) {
    animation: x_2 0.5s forwards ease-in-out;
  }


  @keyframes x_1 {
    0%{
      transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%{
      transform: translateY(11px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
      transform: translateY(11px) rotate(45deg);
    }
  }
  @keyframes x_2 {
    0%{
      transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50%{
      transform: translateY(-11px) rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%{
      transform: translateY(-11px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
  }
```

---

```
function onClick(){
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('navTrigger')[0];
  elem.classList.toggle('inactive');
  elem.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used simple `transform` to do this animation. Kindly check the below snippet.

```js
function onClick(){
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('navTrigger')[0];
  elem.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
a {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
}

.navTrigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 44px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.navTrigger i {
  background: white;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navTrigger i:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translate(0, 10px);
}

.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(15px, 15px);
}

.navTrigger.active i:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="onClick()">
  <span class='navTrigger inactive'>
    <i></i>
    <i ></i>
  </span>
</a>
```

Comment: this works, however, I do want it to work with animation since I want to animate the bar in a specific way (such as the keyframes above). I want both bars to first move into the center then both rotate as I have done with keyframes.

Comment: The same can be done using keyframes too. Let me know in case you are stuck. I can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

May be using 2 toggle methods is creating confusion. Instead of using 2 classes ('active' and 'inactive'), try adding 'active' class when onClick. Default state has simply 'navTrigger' class:

```
  <a onClick = {onClick}>
     <span className = 'navTrigger'>
       <i></i>
       <i ></i>
     </span>
  </a>
```

If it doesn't work as you wish., try using add() and remove() methods instead of toggle() with 'if' condition checking if 'active' class exists...something like this:

```
function onClick(){
   var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('navTrigger')[0];
   var target = elem.classList;
   if(!(target.contains('active'))){
          target.add('inactive');
     } else if (target.contains('active')){
          target.remove('active')
     }
 }
```

If necessary, try using setTimeout(function(){....},....) when toggling 'active' class.

Comment: I have tried what you suggested above but it doesn't seem to do anything. it completely stopped the animation from working altogether.